# Add h1 to a div with viewport set to 100

Tags: html, css, height

I am trying to create a div which is 100 viewheight. Inside the div is a h1 placed. The h1 enlarges the div so it isn't 100 viewheight anymore. It shouldn't have a scrollbar like right now in the example below. I searched on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window) for a answer but didn't found anything.

How can I add a h1 element to a div with 100 viewheight, without enlarging the div?
Why is it enlarging it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div style="height: 100vh; background: yellow;">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `overflow:hidden` if you dont want the content of your div it will remove the scrollbar or if you want to show inside your div then use `position`

```
 div{position:relative}
 h1{position:absolute}
```

This positioning will inscribe the h1 and will show on top of div h1 and will not overflow

Also, you can use the `display` property

```
     div{display:flex;justify-content:space- 
      around;height:100vh}

    h1{ height:auto}
```

This will avoid overflow by flex in one line. If you dont want flex just use height:auto in your h1. It will take upto max width of its parent div